# How to prevent data from appearing on new columns when appending

Tags: python

I have this issue I am not sure how to solve. I am tying to obtain the exchange rates and append it to into one data frame, however how do I stop the number values from appearing on new columns as seen below? Instead have all exchange rates on one column, and a new column that has the FXAUDCAD, FXBRLCAD etc.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

def fx_rates_daily(fx):
    html = requests.get("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/"+fx)
    json_data = json.loads(html.text)
    data_frame = pd.json_normalize(json_data['observations'])
    return data_frame

countries = ['FXAUDCAD', 'FXBRLCAD', 'FXCNYCAD']

fx_rates = pd.DataFrame()
for p in countries:
    data = fx_rates_daily(p)
    fx_rates = fx_rates.append(data)
fx_rates
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html?highlight=pandas%20merge#pandas-merge)

```
fx_rates = pd.DataFrame()
for p in countries:
    data = fx_rates_daily(p)
    fx_rates = data if fx_rates.empty else pd.merge(fx_rates, data, on='d')
```